# No route matches [POST] "/users/1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `link_to` in a view that I would like to use to call a method in my controller to update the model.

Here's the view code:

```
  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tr data-user-id="<%= user.id %>">
        <td><%= user.email %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Admin', user, method: :admin %></td>      

      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
```

this link is the specific one that isnt working, since it's not a default method in the users controller

```
<td><%= link_to 'Admin', user, method: :admin %></td>
```

The admin method in my controller looks like this

```
  def admin
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.isadmin?

      redirect_to '/users', alert: 'User was updated to admin.'

      else
        redirect_to '/users', alert: 'User is already an admin.'
      end

  end
```

I dont have any route defined in the routes.rb file because I'm not sure how to define it correctly. Is there an issue with the view or is an issue with not having a route. I thought that i could specify the controller and action in the link but that doesnt seem to be working.

Here's the console output

```
Started POST "/users/5" for 192.168.1.1 at 2019-03-13 22:25:50 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/users/5"):

actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:65:in `call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:22:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.2.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
rack (2.0.6) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.2.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:225:in `call'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:658:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:472:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/server.rb:332:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:133:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :users
  post 'users/:id' =>  'users#admin'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should create the route you need.

```
post 'users/:id/admin' =>  'users#admin'
```

your link would look like

```
<% = link_to 'Admin', users_admin_path(user) %> # or whatever rails names your route
```

Comment: This didnt work for me, im still getting the same error. Where else might i have an issue?

Comment: @tdepiera1 What is the error? What is the output of running `rails routes` in the console?

Comment: looks like it works if i remote `/admin` and just use `post 'users/:id =>  'users#admin'`

Comment: removing `/admin` is probably linking to your `create` path. Post your routes file above

Comment: added to my post. its definitely not linking to my create method. its calling the admin method exactly as id like it to

Comment: Yeah, that should work. But be sure you haven't broken your update method. Also long as `update` is a patch and not post you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your link to:

```
 <%= link_to "Admin", admin_path(user) %>
```

And your route to:

```
 post 'admin', to: 'admin#users', as: :admin
```

Comment: i tried this but it didnt work for me. the solution above worked

Comment: Because you did not show the full action on controller. For what you showed my solution worked if you used get instead in routes..

Answer (score 0):

In view file your Admin link is incorrect. Method should be :delete, :post etc not :admin

```
<td><%= link_to 'Admin', user, method: :admin %></td>
```

Here's the fix -

**Solution #1**

```
# In view
<td><%= link_to 'Admin', admin_user_path(user) %></td>
```

Route should be

```
resources :users do
 member do
  get 'admin'
 end
end
```

**Solution #2**

```
# In view
<td><%= link_to 'Admin', admin_user_path(user), method: :post %></td>
```

Route should be

```
resources :users do
 member do
  post 'admin'
 end
end
```